# При установке yarn

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarn

```
error upath@1.0.4: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=4 <=9". Got "11.1.0"
error Found incompatible module
```

Comment: текущая версия nodejs не соответствует требуемой. Нужна версия ">=4 <=9" а стоит 11.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yarn config set ignore-engines true

Comment: вот [тут](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5727) говорят, что может не помочь, и лучше удалить из yarn.lock строку для upath и выполнить install